# Getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error when using Async method

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, heap-memory

I am receiving the below error when I am invoking an async method and using ThreadPoolExecutorService.

```
@Bean(name = "taskExecutor")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(5);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(10);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("SyncThread");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
}
```

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/coupons/bulk/syncCoupons", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@Async("taskExecutor")
public ResponseEntity<?> syncShopifyCouponsV4(@RequestBody List<Long> ids) {
    logger.info("Start :: syncShopifyPriceRulesListToMongoV3 for ids size = " + ids.size());
    try {
        if (!ids.isEmpty()) {
            List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = ids.stream()
                    .map(id -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                        logger.info("id inside CompletableFuture: " + id);
                        ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons task = shopifyBulkSyncCoupons;
                        task.setCouponId(id);
                        task.run(); // Manually invoke the run method
                    }, taskExecutor)) // Use your configured taskExecutor here
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            CompletableFuture<Void>[] futureArray = futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]);
            CompletableFuture<Void> allOf = CompletableFuture.allOf(futureArray);
            allOf.join(); // Wait for all tasks to complete
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    logger.info("End :: syncShopifyPriceRulesListToMongoV3");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

```
public void syncShopifyPriceRulesListToMongoV2( Long id)
{
    ShopifyClient shopifyClient1 = new ShopifyClient();
    ShopifyPriceRuleResponse priceRuleResponse = shopifyClient1.getPriceRuleById(id);
    if(null!=priceRuleResponse && null!=priceRuleResponse.getPriceRule()) {
        PriceRuleDetails priceRuleDetails = new PriceRuleDetails();
        List<Long> finalEntitledVariants = new ArrayList<>();
        priceRuleDetails = mapShopifyPriceRuleToModel(priceRuleResponse.getPriceRule());
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledCollectionIds())) {
            List<Long> collectionIds = priceRuleDetails.getEntitledCollectionIds();
            List<ProductAttributes> prodAttr = productAttrRepository.findByCollectionsIn(collectionIds);
            for (ProductAttributes prod : prodAttr) {
                finalEntitledVariants.add(prod.getVariantId());
            }
        }
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledProductIds())) {
            List<ProductAttributes> productAttributesList = productAttrRepository.findByProductIdIn(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledProductIds());
            for (ProductAttributes prod : productAttributesList) {
                finalEntitledVariants.add(prod.getVariantId());
            }
        }
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledVariantIds())) {
            finalEntitledVariants.addAll(priceRuleDetails.getEntitledVariantIds());
        }
        priceRuleDetails.setEntitledVariantIds(finalEntitledVariants);
        priceRuleDetailsRepo.save(priceRuleDetails);
    }

}
```

```
public class ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons implements Runnable
{

    private static final Logger logger = 
    Logger.getLogger(PriceRuleServiceImpl.class);
    private  Long couponId ;

    public ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons(Long couponId) {
        this.couponId = couponId;
    }

    public Long getCouponId() {
        return couponId;
    }

    public void setCouponId(Long couponId) {
        couponId = couponId;
    }

    @Override
    @Async("taskExecutor")
    public void run()
    {
        logger.info("Inside run for id "+couponId+" Thread is 
       "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
         PriceRuleServiceImpl priceRuleService = new 
         PriceRuleServiceImpl();
         priceRuleService.
         syncShopifyPriceRulesListToMongoV2(couponId);
    }
}
```

I tried by removing the line executor.setQueueCapacity(10); but still getting the same error. Can someone please point out what is wrong here.

Comment: How many ids are you operating on?

Comment: @M.Deinum the no of ids can be variable however for testing purposes I am using 11 ids . When I do this sequentially the performance is better compared to when using this approach . I tried by changing the core and max pool size to 4 , it does work then but the performance is even slow compared to sequential processing

Comment: Then either your heap size is way too small or you are creating and retaining a lot of objects in memory (without knowing what your `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons` does this would be impossible to answer. Instead of calling `run` you might be even better of making `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons` a `Runnable` and create a constructor for the `id` saves you a bit of code and an anonymous class. Also `@Async` on an controller is a bit weird and doesn't add anything here. This also feels dangerous as the `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons` seems to be a singleton that gets replaced in-flight.

Comment: @M.Deinum my ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons class does implement Runnable .

Comment: I find this `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons task = shopifyBulkSyncCoupons;` dangerous. As it re-assigns values to a singleton instance of `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons` in a multi-threaded environment. This is trouble waiting to happen. I would expect something like `new ShopifyBylkSyncCoupons(id);` which wouldn't need a call to `run` either. But as stated, you either have a very low memory settings or are retaining a lot of object for too long. Please add `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons` to your question.

Comment: Why are you creating a new service, that feels wrong, there is also no autowired field, so it feels like dumbed down code instead of oactual code.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This answer is sort of a work-in-progress.

Issues with the code:

1. `@Async` on the controller method, which should be on a service method (including the code in the controller) or properly utilize the async servlet API.
2. Re-using a single instance `ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons` to re-use an `id` property in a multi-threaded environment is trouble waiting to happen.

### `@Async` to service method

The `@Async` should be on a service method and the code which is in the controller, should be moved to that method as well. That way the controller will return quickly and promptly. Or properly use the async servlet API by returning a `[Completable]Future` or `Callable` from the controller method.

### Re-use of a singleton instance

The code inside the lambda indicates re-use of a statefuo singleton in a multithreaded environment. Don't do things like this as that is trouble waiting to happen.

```java
ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons task = shopifyBulkSyncCoupons;
task.setCouponId(id);
task.run(); // Manually invoke the run method
```

## Modified code

Actual runnable

```java
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons {

  private final long couponId;

  @Autowired
  private final SomeRepository repo;

  public ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons(long couponId) {
    this.couponId = couponId;
  }
  // Other methods
}
```

Service

```java
public MyProcessingService {

  private final AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;
  private final ApplicationContext context;

  public MyProcessingService(AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor, ApplicationContext context) {
    this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Async("taskExecutor")
  public CompletableFuture<Void> processCoupons(List<Long> ids) {
    logger.info("Start :: syncShopifyPriceRulesListToMongoV3 for ids size = " + ids.size());
    
    CompletableFuture<Void>[] futures = 
     ids.stream()
       .map( (id) -> this.context.getBean(ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons.class, id))
       .map( (task) -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, taskExecutor)
       .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);

     return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
  }
}
```

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/coupons/bulk/syncCoupons", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public CompletableFuture<Void> syncShopifyCouponsV4(@RequestBody List<Long> ids) { 
  return service.processCoupons(ids);
```

Comment: thanks for giving the improved version of code . by doing new ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons(id) I get an error like APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.johnjacobs.catalog.config.ShopifyBulkSyncCoupons required a bean of type 'java.lang.Long' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Long' in your configuration. my class is annotated with Component .

Comment: You shouldn't be annotating that class with `@Component` nor inject it, just create an instance as this is more or less a task. Unless you need dependency injection, you could make it a prototype and use the context to create an instance (and discard it afterwards). But as requested we need to see the specific class to determine what to do.

Comment: I have a few places where i need to use the derived query methods to fetch result and process them therefore I need to autowire the repository and use the bean to call find method . Through an instance created with new that won't be possible .

Please see the edited code snippet .

Comment: You can make it a prototype scoped bean to let Spring create instances as needed or autowire it after creation using the beanfactory/applicationcontext. Either way you either still have too little memory or are retaining too many objects. But the actual import part (which does the work) still isn't in your question. It also feels you are using the wrong tool for the job and this is something that should be run with Spring Batch for instance.